# What value does the area of the region enclosed by $\sum_{k=1}^m (x^k+y^k)=2$ converge to as $m\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, curves, riemann-integration

Find the area enclosed by the curve

$$\sum_{k=1}^m (x^k+y^k)=2$$

where $m$ is even and $m \rightarrow\infty$.

That is for a sufficiently large even number $m$, we have:

$$x^1+y^1+x^2+y^2+x^3+y^3+\dots+x^m+y^m=2$$

See the graph of the curve ($m=250$): the $250$ here is to illustrate the region, but the required area to be calculated when $m$ is even that is tending to infinity.

[image]

---

WHAT I DID:

I tried to convert the equation of the curve, which has an infinite series, into a function of $x$ where $x>0 ,y>0$.

After very long and difficult steps, I got the area $(A)$ enclosed by that curve as:

$$A=\int_0^{\frac{12}{7}}\frac{7x-12}{4x-7}dx=3-\frac{1}{8}\ln(7)\approx 2.75676 \text{ unit}^2$$.

---

I. Is my answer right?

II. How can we solve it easily? I used $5$ pages to solve it.

---

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: The region seems to get smaller as $m$ becomes larger.

Comment: @Allawonder Yes, get smaller as $m$ becomes larger. But FINITELY smaller.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Oops, I just realised I totally misunderstood your question -- I had thought all the $k$ were even as well. The limit of your curves gives a rational function, as one of the answers below hints.

Comment: I have looked at it again. As $m\to+\infty,$ the equation becomes $$y=\frac{2-3x}{3-4x},$$ which is a rational function and hence doesn't enclose a finite region. So the question seems ill-posed.

Comment: Also, your answer for $A$ is not the region bounded by the curve (since there's no such finite region). You're only calculated the region bounded by that hyperbola and the curves $x=0,y=0$ and $x=12/7.$

Comment: @Allawonder try to see the graph of $y=\frac{7x-12}{4x-7}$ in the first quadrant. Is not that equivalent to the required area?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari As I've said above, in the first quadrant, your curve *and* the axes bound a finite region (up to a point), but unless I'm mistaken that cannot be the same as the area needed since the curves are not always symmetric with respect to the axes. The case for $m=250$ sketched above shows this.

Comment: @Allawonder I am sure that you did not get me right. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sauryu6ebc, for different even $m$'s $2,4,6,8,10,12,14$. All are even. My question for even large $m$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I got you right. My point is that those curves are not always closed. In particular, the limiting curve is a hyperbola, so that there's no finite region bounded by the curve.

Comment: @Allawonder those curves are always closed. Tell me please when those curves are not closed? Waiting for some examples. THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some obvious stuff.

$\begin{array}\\
2
&=\sum_{k=1}^m (x^k+y^k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m x^k+\sum_{k=1}^m y^k\\
&=\dfrac{x-x^{m+1}}{x-1}+\dfrac{y-y^{m+1}}{y-1}\\
&\to \dfrac{x}{x-1}+\dfrac{y}{y-1}
\qquad\text{as }m \to \infty\\
&= \dfrac{x-1+1}{x-1}+\dfrac{y-1+1}{y-1}\\
&= 1+\dfrac{1}{x-1}+1+\dfrac{1}{y-1}\\
\text{so}\\
0
&= \dfrac{1}{x-1}+\dfrac{1}{y-1}\\
&= \dfrac{(y-1)+(x-1)}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
&= \dfrac{x+y-2}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
&\text{just a line}\\
2
&=\dfrac{x-x^{m+1}}{x-1}+\dfrac{y-y^{m+1}}{y-1}\\
&=\dfrac{x(1-x^{m})}{x-1}+\dfrac{y(1-y^{m})}{y-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(y-1)(x-x^{m+1})+(x-1)(y-y^{m+1})}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{(y-1)x-(y-1)x^{m+1}+(x-1)y-(x-1)y^{m+1}}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2xy-x-y-(y-1)x^{m+1}-(x-1)y^{m+1}}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
\text{so}\\
0
&=\dfrac{2xy-x-y-(y-1)x^{m+1}-(x-1)y^{m+1}-2(x-1)(y-1)}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2xy-x-y-2(xy-x-y+1)-(y-1)x^{m+1}-(x-1)y^{m+1}}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{x+y-2-(y-1)x^{m+1}-(x-1)y^{m+1}}{(x-1)(y-1)}\\
\text{or}\\
0
&=x+y-2-(y-1)x^{m+1}-(x-1)y^{m+1}\\
&=(x-1)+(y-1)-(y-1)x^{m+1}-(x-1)y^{m+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Don't know how much this helps,
but here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Two geometric series:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k \ge 1} (x^k + y^k)
    &= \frac{1}{1 - x} - 1 + \frac{1}{1 - y} - 1 \\
    &= \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{1}{1 - y} - 2
\end{align*}$

I'm sure you can take it from here...

Comment: That's a linear rational function. They are never closed curves. In particular this is a hyperbola.

Comment: @Allawonder [It looks like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F%281-x%29%2B1%2F%281-y%29%3C4) the region is infinite.